# Calculate coordinates of certain function using the transformation matrix of a certain basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a vector space spanned by the functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) =\sin(x)$ & $g(x) =\cos(x)$.
>
> Find $[l]_C$ using the transformation matrix, where:
>
> $B = \{f, g\}$ the standard basis.
>
> $C = \{2\sin(x) +\cos(x), 3\cos(x)\}$
>
> and $l = 5\sin(x) -2\cos(x)$.

I've found that the matrix is:
$M_{B\rightarrow C} = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$

But when I multiply the matrix by the coordinates of $l$ by the standard basis, I don't get a correct result.

$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\1&3\end{bmatrix}· \begin{bmatrix}5\\-2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}10\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

This doesn't make sense, as $10(2\sin(x) +\cos(x)) -1(3\cos(x)) \ne 5\sin(x) -2\cos(x)$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And what is $B$?

Comment: I've edited the post, B is the standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that $M_{B\to C}$ is incorrect.

Note that $[f]_C=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\-1/6\end{bmatrix}$ and $[g]_C=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1/3\end{bmatrix}$, giving$$M_{B\to C}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\-1/6&1/3\end{bmatrix}$$which gives $[l]_C=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\-1/6&1/3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5\\-2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5/2\\-3/2\end{bmatrix}$, which is correct since $\frac52(2f+g)-\frac32(3g)=5f-2g$ as desired.